# Proposing new tag for the Bioinformatics channel

Tags: discussion

I am a synthetic biologist working heavily on the modeling of genetic circuits and the development of software for bioinformatics. Many researchers and software developers within bioinformatics rely heavily on data standards to more easily share information between researchers and software tools. One such standard is thy Synthetic Biology Open Language ([SBOL](https://www.nature.com/articles/nbt.2891)), where you can describe genetic circuits, function, experimental data, and much more.

The SBOL is a growing community withing bioinformatics and an increasing number of software tools and databases support SBOL in one way or another. However, it is a complex data model and many users might need this channel to ask/answer questions related to SBOL and probably other data models in this area of research.

I want to propose to add a tag for **SBOL**, so that users of this community that *do* use standards can tag appropriately and get answers related to this data standard.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If there are no objections within a day or so remind me to create the tag.

Comment: Just to be clear (and maybe you already know this), there is nothing stopping users from adding the `sbol` tag to posts now. Questions about SBOL and related topics are certainly on-topic for this site, and we'd welcome more engagement from that sub-community. Things like tags and tag descriptions are typically an indicator of (not a prerequisite for) community involvement. But I fully support Devon adding the tag and a description so that it will appear as a suggestion and an auto-complete candidate for relevant questions in the future.

Comment: I just saw another question about modeling with SBML, and I added the tags `systems-biology` and `sbml` which had not existed before. Any user with ≥150 reputation can create a new tag. https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags

Comment: Perfect thanks. Yeah I don't have the rating to add tags yet. The other widely used standard for model simulations is SED-ML

Comment: Hello, @DevonRyan. This is a friendly reminder to add the SBOL tag. Thank you!

Comment: I'll add that now. Thanks @DanielStandage for adding the others!