# Propose new tags for the COMBNE community

Tags: discussion, tags

I asked a question yesterday regarding the posting of questions related to COMBINE standards and got a positive answer. However in order for a reader to filter questions related to specific COMBINE standards would it be possible create a series of new tags? I don't have enough reputation on this stack exchange to create them myself. I noticed an [earlier question](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/proposing-new-tag-for-the-bioinformatics-channel) that requested a tag for SBOL which is itself a COMBINE standard and there was a positive response to that. A set of additional tags would include:

SBML

SBGN

CELLML

BIOPAX

NEUROML

SEDML

Further information on these standards can be found at the [COMBINE web site.](http://co.mbine.org/)

Comment: Just post a question and the tags can be created. We can't create tags without questions.

Comment: ok didn't realize. Here is one question I posted a few days ago that could use the tags SBML and libSBML. [link](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/9010/how-can-i-translate-infix-to-mathml-using-the-python-interface-to-libsbml)

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Daniel [already tagged that](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/proposing-new-tag-for-the-bioinformatics-channel#comment1433_205) with the new tags.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I’ll post some other questions that can be tagged with the others proposed tags in the coming days

Comment: That's great! Welcome aboard!